# Telegram Webhook returns a 302 error in yii2

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2, telegram, yii2-advanced-app

I can't figure out how to configure the address in yii2 so that telegram doesn't return a 302 error

in the root and /frontend in the .htaccess files these settings

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

IndexIgnore /
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin\/?(.*) /backend/web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|admin|site/webhook)
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /backend/web/index.php [L]
```

In the SiteController of the frontend

```
public function actionSetWebhook()
{
    Yii::$app->telegram->setWebhook([
        'url' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['site/webhook']),
    ]);

}
public function actionWebhook()
{
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
}
```

The webhook is installed without errors, but when sending a message using the getWebhookInfo method, the telegram gives the following error

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://домен/site/webhook","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":35,"last_error_date":1680856667,"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 302 Found","max_connections":40,"ip_address":"айпи"}}
```

runtime/logs/app.log

```
2023-04-07 11:37:47 [айпи][-][-][info][application] $_GET = [
    'r' => 'site/webhook'
]

$_POST = []

$_FILES = []

$_COOKIE = []

$_SERVER = [
    'REDIRECT_HTTPS' => 'on'
    'REDIRECT_downgrade-1_0' => ''
    'REDIRECT_suppress-error-charset' => ''
    'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200'
    'HTTPS' => 'on'
    'downgrade-1_0' => ''
    'suppress-error-charset' => ''
    'HTTP_HOST' => 'домен'
    'HTTP_X_REAL_IP' => 'айпи'
    'HTTP_X_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1'
    'HTTP_X_SERVER_IP' => 'айпи'
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL' => 'https'
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO' => 'https'
    'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'close'
    'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '444'
    'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip, deflate'
    'PATH' => '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin'
    'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => ''
    'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'Apache'
    'SERVER_NAME' => 'домен'
    'SERVER_ADDR' => 'айпи'
    'SERVER_PORT' => '80'
    'REMOTE_ADDR' => 'айпи'
    'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/home/users/o/аккаунт/domains/домен'
    'REQUEST_SCHEME' => 'http'
    'CONTEXT_PREFIX' => ''
    'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/home/users/o/аккаунт/domains/домен'
    'SERVER_ADMIN' => 'info@jino.ru'
    'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/home/users/o/аккаунт/domains/домен/frontend/web/index.php'
    'REMOTE_PORT' => '36426'
    'REDIRECT_URL' => '/site/webhook'
    'REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING' => 'r=site/webhook'
    'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1'
    'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.0'
    'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST'
    'QUERY_STRING' => 'r=site/webhook'
    'REQUEST_URI' => '/site/webhook'
    'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/frontend/web/index.php'
    'PHP_SELF' => '/frontend/web/index.php'
    'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1680856667.8266
    'REQUEST_TIME' => 1680856667
]
```

if webhook set to a file in the root of the site (not in the frontend), I get the data, but I need to add a record in the database, and from the parent category can not do it

Comment: 302 is redirect, so you should follow redirect. E.g. redirect from `http` to `https`

Comment: I understand that. The problem is that I do not understand how to remove and what kind of redirect. In the logs, 'REDIRECT_URL' => '/site/webhook' and 'REQUEST_URI' => '/site/webhook' are

Answer (score 0):

You actually want `site/webhook` to be handled by `SiteController`, so you need RewriteRule to your Yii2 app. Just update your line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|admin|site/webhook)
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|admin)
```

And then add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/webhook
RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php [L]
```

If it's part of backend then update this new rule to redirect to it. If you want Yii2 code to handle the request, there should a rule that will redirect it to `index.php` file and that will call the controller action.

Comment: I get the same error. "Wrong response from the webhook: 302 Found"

Comment: Do you use app authentication? Maybe that action requires user to log in and that's generating the redirect.
Can you try to access the action from a browser and add here access.log lines from that time? Please use incognito mode of the browser, so no cookies are reused.